# IMediator Mock returns null when I set up it in test

Tags: c#, .net-core, moq, xunit, mediator

Here is my code:

```
public sealed class BulkAddStockConditionItemCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand,
    UserStockConditionSetsEntity>
{

    private readonly IMediator _mediator;


    public BulkAddStockConditionItemCommandHandler(IMediator mediator)
    {

        _mediator = mediator;
  
    }

    public async Task<UserStockConditionSetsEntity> Handle(BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var conditionalRiskAgreements = new ConditionalRiskAgreementEntity(_userService.CustomerIsin);

        var addRes = await _mediator.Send(new AcceptConditionalRiskAgreementCommand(), cancellationToken);

        if (addRes == null) throw new Exception();


        //...code removed for brevity
    }
}
```

I inject the `IMediator` into my constructor and I need the `addRes` not be `NULL` in my unit test scenario, so here you can see my test scenario:

```
public async void BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand_when_StockConditionSet_is_null()
{
    //arrange
    
    var condition = new ConditionalRiskAgreementEntity(RandomIsin);

    var mediator = new Mock<IMediator>();

    mediator.Setup(i => i.Send(It.IsAny<ConditionalRiskAgreementEntity>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(Task.FromResult<object>(condition));

    BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand command = new BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand(data);
    BulkAddStockConditionItemCommandHandler handler = new BulkAddStockConditionItemCommandHandler(mediator.Object, userservice.Object, repoacc.Object, CacheableRepository.Object);

    //Act

    var caughtException = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => handler.Handle(command, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()));

    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<Exception>(caughtException);

}
```

I set up the `IMediator` as but when I run the test it returns `null` instead of `condition`  variable. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the shown code, the subject under test uses `AcceptConditionalRiskAgreementCommand`

```
//...

var addRes = await _mediator.Send(new AcceptConditionalRiskAgreementCommand(), cancellationToken);

//...
```

but in the test the mocked mediator is setup to expect `ConditionalRiskAgreementEntity`

```
//...

mediator.Setup(i => i.Send(It.IsAny<ConditionalRiskAgreementEntity>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(Task.FromResult<object>(condition));

//...
```

The mock will return *null* by default when the argument matchers do not match in the invoked member.

There is no need to return `Task.FromResult<object>(condition)` in `ReturnsAsync` since that will wrap whatever you pass in a `Task`

First I suggest you refactor the test to use `async Task` instead of `async void` and then update the mock to expect the actual argument types used in the subject under test.

```
public async Task BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand_when_StockConditionSet_is_null() {
    //Arrange
    var condition = new ConditionalRiskAgreementEntity(RandomIsin);

    var mediator = new Mock<IMediator>();

    mediator
        .Setup(i => i.Send(It.IsAny<AcceptConditionalRiskAgreementCommand>(), It.IsAny<System.Threading.CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(condition);

    BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand command = new BulkAddStockConditionItemCommand(data);
    BulkAddStockConditionItemCommandHandler handler = new BulkAddStockConditionItemCommandHandler(mediator.Object, userservice.Object, repoacc.Object, CacheableRepository.Object);

    //Act
    var caughtException = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(() => handler.Handle(command, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()));

    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<Exception>(caughtException);
}
```